# Determine if the function is uniformly continuous

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Determine if the function: $$f(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$  $\forall x>1$ is uniformly continuous.

I know that it is not. But I'm having trouble proving it.
I reach to a point that i get this: $$\frac{|x-y||1-xy|}{(1-x)^2(1-y)^2} \le \delta|1-xy|$$ and I cannot continue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try finding a Cauchy sequence $x_n$ that fails to map to a Cauchy sequence. Try thinking of a sequence $x_n$ that converges to $1$, but is strictly greater than $1$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F(1-x)%5E2 may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=\infty$. So, for any $\delta>0$, you can find $x,y\in(1,1+\delta)$ such that $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert\geqslant1$. But $\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta$.

Comment: Do we need to prove that in a neighborhood of 1 we get $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge 1$?

Comment: I didn't say that. Actually, I don't even know what it *means*. What I wrote was that in $(1,1+\delta)$ **there are** elements $x$ and $y$ such that $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert\geqslant1$.